# Why a certain field causes a slow query?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I have 6 almost identical queries on a page. I am loading logs by keyname.

Lattitude and longitude take over 4s each, where as 4 other values take 0.09s How could just the one text value in where query cause that, see the 2 queries below.

This query takes 4 seconds:

```
SELECT
  h0_.keyname AS keyname_0,
  h0_.sensorvalue AS sensorvalue_1,
  h0_.receiveddate AS receiveddate_2,
  DATE_FORMAT(h0_.receiveddate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS sclr_3
FROM history h0_
WHERE h0_.company_id = 1
  AND h0_.receiveddate > '2019-05-01 14:00'
  AND h0_.receiveddate < '2019-05-01 17:01'
  AND h0_.keyname = 'longitude'
  AND h0_.device_id = 9
GROUP BY sclr_3;
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                            | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h0_   | NULL       | range | IDX_27BA704B979B1AD6,IDX_27BA704B94A4C7D4,receiveddate,keyname,device_id | receiveddate | 5       | NULL | 24022 |     0.15 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This query takes 0.09 seconds:

```
SELECT
  h0_.keyname AS keyname_0,
  h0_.sensorvalue AS sensorvalue_1,
  h0_.receiveddate AS receiveddate_2,
  DATE_FORMAT(h0_.receiveddate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS sclr_3
FROM history h0_
WHERE h0_.company_id = 1
  AND h0_.receiveddate > '2019-05-01 14:00'
  AND h0_.receiveddate < '2019-05-01 17:01'
  AND h0_.keyname = 'temperature'
  AND h0_.device_id = 9
GROUP BY sclr_3;
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                            | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h0_   | NULL       | range | IDX_27BA704B979B1AD6,IDX_27BA704B94A4C7D4,receiveddate,keyname,device_id | receiveddate | 5       | NULL | 24022 |     0.48 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Here are some specifics:

- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux
- Ubuntu 18
- 6GB RAM
- 2 CPU

This table has the following

```
    CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiveddate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `keyname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sensorvalue` decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_27BA704B979B1AD6` (`company_id`),
  KEY `IDX_27BA704B94A4C7D4` (`device_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26656 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: It's generally more useful when you post your table and index definitions in the form of DDL statements as opposed to screenshots.

Comment: One other piece of information that might be helpful here is the query plan (`EXPLAIN` output). Or rather two query plans, the slow one and the fast one.

Comment: Given the same company and device IDs and the date range, would there be  (approximately) the same number of temperature and longitude readings?

Comment: Normally yes, but for this date range, there was only 1 longitude and hundreds of temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing to explain the timing difference.  However, I see some things to improve.  They might even improve on the 0.09s.

```
WHERE h0_.company_id = 1
  AND h0_.receiveddate > '2019-05-01 14:00'
  AND h0_.receiveddate < '2019-05-01 17:01'
  AND h0_.keyname = 'longitude'
  AND h0_.device_id = 9
```

Begs for a 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(company_id, key_name, device_id, -- in any order
      receivedate)
```

This is a strange range; it is 3 hours + 1 minute - 1 second:

```
  AND h0_.receiveddate > '2019-05-01 14:00'
  AND h0_.receiveddate < '2019-05-01 17:01'
```

`decimal(20,10)` seems excessive.  It takes 10 bytes and has more precision than virtually any consumer-grade sensor.  Consider a 4-byte `FLOAT` (with no (m,n)).

Are you receiving multiple values in a *minute*?  If so, the `GROUP BY` is improper.  The output will pick one of the possible sensorvalues and receivedates, and they may even correspond to each other.  Either remove the `GROUP BY` or do some kind of aggregate, such as `AVG()`.

How many different `keyname` values?  Is 255 needed in `varchar(255)`?  Do you have millions of rows, and this is a rather bulky part of the table?  See also `ENUM`.

Comment: I will try some of those suggestions. We receive 100 rows of data per second. The receive date in the query is user input for the report range they want

Comment: It seems float is not accurate enough for the GPS sensor which also saves here

Comment: thanks @rick-james I so far only upvoted your comment because I am still testing. table is 10m rows so far, so taking a while. I'll run a few tests after. I guess float won't work, although your explanation amkes perfect sense as to how that would help. GPS has too many decimal places it seems? I saw this post which sheds some light https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitude-in-a-mysql

Comment: Rick, the query itself is now fast, both of them.
I did not yet implement the AVG()

I marked your answer as correct. I am still experiencing issues, but it seems PHP now, because the page is crashing running out of memory ... so I work on that next

Comment: @TDawg - `FLOAT` provides 1.7m (5.6ft) of resolution.  For houses or trucks, that should be adequate; for people, maybe not.  Google's map coordinates can distinguish two fleas on a dog.  But I don't know of a flea tracking app.

Comment: @TDawg - PHP has a default memory limit, but it can be raised.  However, I recommend figuring out why PHP is running out of memory and see if some other action can be taken.  For example, if you are fetching a million rows from the table to work on them, perhaps SQL could summarize the data (eg AVG), thereby decreasing how much is shipped to PHP -- and shrinking the network time to send the data.

Comment: re: FLOAT, I saw a post linking to a page with your chart on that. But, when I changed my script to use float was 4 decimal lace. So, I needed my bosses feedback. Pending :)

Comment: re: PHP memory, I tested on a query which responds with 400,000 rows in a chart. The data was SO much, it was a useless chart. So, I grouped by minute, limiting to 60 rows. The page no longer crashes. The query takes 3s, and total page load time is just over 10s. A 3hr subset of data grouped by minute is 20s, and then a day grouped by hour (24 rows) takes almost 25-30s

In all cases, there is no MYSQL query taking more than 5s. even the most complicated ones. 20m rows of data at this point.

Comment: @TDawg - Do not use `FLOAT(7,4)`, use plain `FLOAT`.  Or did you mean something else by your Comment?

Comment: @TDawg - `GROUP BY` - Consider building and maintaining a Summary Table(s) that has subtotals for perhaps each hour.  That would make day or week charts much faster to fetch the data for.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: @TDawg - I commented on `keyname`.  I still don't see why longitude would be any slower than temp.  Oh, wait -- The `EXPLAINs` show it using an index that is not in the `CREATE TABLE`???